# How can I convert a .docx file to pdf using Ghostscript on a ubuntu server with php

Tags: php, linux, ghostscript, docx

I would like to convert existing docx files into pdfs on the server. Can anybody provide code examples of how I can achieve this please. My intention is to use the php exec() command to fire any command line arguments needed.

thanks.

Comment: i don't think that's currently possible. docx being the newest extension from MS

Comment: maybe http://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux could help

Comment: Also [this answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/170073/39201), mentioning [jodconvertor](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/)

Comment: @AaronW. I found that question when researching but it mentions doc files not docx

Comment: @Wrikken In this instance that is not an option as openoffice destroys the formatting of the docx files

Comment: @I-CRE8: are you sure? _my_ Open Office (or actually Libre Office) can open docx just fine, thankyouverymuch. Are you running the latest?

Comment: Also, `docx` was new in _7 December 2006_.... Not terribly new now...

Comment: @Wrikken yes I am sure, I didn't say I couldn't open it I said it destroyed the format of the document

Comment: OK, then I maybe I haven't come across the more exotic layout issues you encounter, most docx's here are pretty straightforward and translate fine (_including_ formatting). For now I stand corrected then, but in that case, you most likely need a windows box somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the process I went through to solve this issue was to use [PHPDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) to create the dynamic docx files, I then had the host install libreoffice on the server and I used that in headless mode to create the pdfs from the docx files and finally I used [PDF Merger](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) to join the pdf files together

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called Docmosis that you could invoke to do DOCX->PDF.  It uses java/openoffice/libre-office/odf-converter together to get the  conversion chain working with reasonable fidelity.  You could use Docmosis or try combining openoffice/libreoffice and odf-converter yourself.  Certainly without odf-converter the docx formatting is poorly rendered by OpenOffice and LibreOffice.